# Virtual folders work differently in VS 2008 between Windows XP & Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Easier to demonstrate this with two screenshots, the first Windows XP, the second Windows 7:

http://www.picpaste.com/Virtual_folders1-4tCBM9lK.PNG
http://www.picpaste.com/Virtual_folders2-pboFc6vf.PNG

In Windows XP, VS 2008 spots the virtual directories and doesn't display or even look at the contents of the virtual directories in the project. This is a very useful feature if your website has a data or temp folder in the same site that isn't part of the source safe. It doesn't, for example, attempt to add the contents of the virtual directory into VSS.

On Windows 7, it works slightly differently. It still doesn't add the files into Visual SourceSafe (thank goodness) but it does:

1. Shows the files in the IDE which is okay except...
2. It therefore searches them which can be very annoying
3. But finally, it also UPLOADS them to the target web server when publishing

It's this latter one that's a pain as one of my temporary folder can contain thousands of small temporary files.

Anyway to make VS 2008 work the same way on W7 as it does on XP?

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude them?